# Подсчёт времени python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, время

Пользователь вводит количество часов и минут. Возможны все комбинации, т.е введёт только часы или только минуты,а может и вовсе не ввести. В последнем случае понятно как отловить, но я не могу разобраться как просчитывать их отдельно, строю кучу проверок в бесконечном цикле, что ни то, ни другое не есть хорошо. Окончательный результат выводить надо в минутах.
Время задаётся в окне tkinter, а просчёт времени в отдельном потоке.

```
def time_thread():
try:
    set_hour = int(hour_set.get())
except:
    set_hour = 0

if set_hour > 0:
    second = set_hour * 3600
else:
    second = 0

set_min = 0
try:
    set_min = int(minute_set.get())
except:
    pass

sc2.destroy()
while 1:
    a = 60
    if set_min >= 0:
        minute = second // a + set_min
        #minute = set_min * a
        print(minute)
    else:
        minute = second // a
    hour = minute // a

    ps2_state.config(text=f"Оставшееся время: {minute} минут")
    second = second - 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понял суть вашего вопроса, но как я понял, вы не можете просчитать конкретно сколько минут осталось. Если это так, то я напишу вам решение, а вы подстройте его под ваш код, просто не совсем могу понять то, чего именно вы хотите.

```
    #получаем на вход количество часов, минут, секунд вне зависимости от того, сколько чего будет
    #то есть, если мы получим на вход количество часов 0.5, а количество минут 72,
    #нам это не помешает
   
    gotten_hours = int(input('Введите количество часов: '))
    gotten_minutes = int(input('Введите количество минут: '))
    gotten_seconds = int(input('Введите количество секунд: '))
    
    #вносим в переменную количество секунд, что даёт нам возможность просчитать уже любую
    #бОльшую величину без проблем

    total_seconds = gotten_hours * 3600 + gotten_minutes * 60 + gotten_seconds

    #просчитываем количество оставшихся минут
    #количество минут без знаков после запятой:

    total_minutes = total_seconds // 60

    #или же со знаками после запятой:

    total_minutes = total_seconds / 60

    #выводим:

    print(total_minutes)
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Не додумался сделать общую секундную переменную.